# Getting the ID of an inserted row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to get the id of the newly inserted record from the database using the sql output clause, i.e.

```
insert into table1(forename, surname) output inserted.id values(@forename, @surname)
```

and I am trying to capture the id like this:

```
Int32 id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar;
```

This is giving me an error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ExecuteScalar' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is a large extract of the existing code:

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
{
    using (command = new SqlCommand("insert into table1(forename, surname) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID values(@forename, @surname)", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@forename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = forename;
        command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = surname;

        command.Connection.Open();
        id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar()`. You just left the parens off.

Answer (score 3):

ExecuteScalar is a method, so you have to put an argument list after it: ExecuteScalar().

Any time you get an error about MethodGroups, this is probably the mistake.